# Editing a closed post should not automatically cast a reopen vote without prior warning

Tags: feature-request, edits, review, closed-questions, vote-to-reopen

I just ran into [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16524597/php-good-practice-reading-post-variables) in the *Reopen Votes* queue. The reason for the Reopen Vote showed 'it has been edited', so I looked up what had been changed, and saw that the topicstarter had added a moderation flame at the end ("Shame this topic is closed").

Since the topic itself hadn't been changed I wasn't planning on disagreeing with the democratic close decision, so I just edited the post to undo the vandalism and reject the reopen vote afterwards. Except that my editing was automatically interpreted by the system as a reopen vote, and so it's currently going back to the rounds with my endorsement. Without warning I inadvertently took an action exactly opposed to my intentions.

I probably should've used rollback instead (hopefully that doesn't auto-cast the reopen vote?), but still in this case I think I should've gotten a warning anyway that this was about to happen? Can editors please get a nice popup like with bounties saying *"does your edit mean you wish to nominate it for reopening?"* or something?

Comment: I don't think this should be shown to the OP, but I think it should be shown to everyone with >2K rep.

Comment: Yeah indeed, OP should be able to improve his post, and for him it automatically means he thinks it should be reopened - but for those of us with full edit privileges it doesn't make sense that cleaning up junk should by definition mean we want it back open on the site.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The review in question: https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/2104282

When you go to the Reopen Votes queue, there are a few options to choose from:

- Leave Closed
- Edit and Reopen
- Reopen
- Skip

[image: reopen options]

You have chosen "Edit and Reopen", and that's the warning you get before it casts a reopen vote.

[image: Edit and Reopen]

To just edit the post without casting a vote, click on "link" to open the question in a new page, press "edit", and choose "Leave Closed" in the original queue.

[image]
[image]

The system does not cast any reopen votes if you just edit the post in the usual manner.

Comment: Got me confused now, since I'm pretty sure I did exactly what you described (but admittedly not 100% sure). Are you sure editing doesn't implicitly take the 'Edit and Reopen' course if there *is* a pending reopen vote on it?

Comment: @Niels Your review action is logged as "Edit and Reopen". If you had opened the question in a new page/tab and clicked the normal edit link, there wouldn't have been a review action recorded at all.

Comment: Well I'm completely open to a mistake on my side causing the confusion, but then this topic illustrates all the more that a) people should be able to revoke close/reopen votes and b) the review interface needs the non-voting edit button in place. Forcing us to open new tabs does invite making mistakes and clicking wrong buttons.